# react-native-bottom-sheet not scrolling when dynamic snapPoints are used

Tags: react-native

Despite using the `BottomSheetScrollView` from [react-native-bottom-sheet](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/), the content is still not scrollable. The issue appears only when the `BottomSheet` is using the `useBottomSheetDynamicSnapPoints` hook. Is there a specific property or component composition the I am missing?

```js
  const sheetRef = useRef<BottomSheet>(null);

  // variables
  const data = useMemo(
    () =>
      Array(50)
        .fill(0)
        .map((_, index) => `index-${index}`),
    [],
  );

  const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ["CONTENT_HEIGHT"], []);

  // callbacks
  const handleSheetChange = useCallback((index: any) => {
    console.log("handleSheetChange", index);
  }, []);
  const handleSnapPress = useCallback((index: any) => {
    sheetRef.current?.snapToIndex(index);
  }, []);
  const handleClosePress = useCallback(() => {
    sheetRef.current?.close();
  }, []);

  // render
  const renderItem = useCallback(
    (item: any) => (
      <View key={item} style={styles.itemContainer}>
        <Text>{item}</Text>
      </View>
    ),
    [],
  );

  const {
    animatedHandleHeight,
    animatedSnapPoints,
    animatedContentHeight,
    handleContentLayout,
  } = useBottomSheetDynamicSnapPoints(snapPoints);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Button onPress={() => handleSnapPress(0)}>Open</Button>
      <Button onPress={() => handleClosePress()}>Close</Button>
      <BottomSheet
        ref={sheetRef}
        index={-1}
        onChange={handleSheetChange}
        snapPoints={animatedSnapPoints}
        handleHeight={animatedHandleHeight}
        contentHeight={animatedContentHeight}>
        <BottomSheetScrollView onLayout={handleContentLayout}>
          {data.map(renderItem)}
        </BottomSheetScrollView>
      </BottomSheet>
    </View>
  );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`useBottomSheetDynamicSnapPoints` doesn't work for for me too, but the following steps helped me:

1. Use **useState** for `snapPoints`
2. Update `snapPoints` value with `onLayout` event.

```js
const NAVIGATION_HEIGHT = 40;

const ActionSheet = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [snapPoints, setSnapPoints] = useState('25%');

  const onContentLayout = useCallback(
    ({
      nativeEvent: {
        layout: { height },
      },
    }) => setSnapPoints([height + NAVIGATION_HEIGHT]),
    []
  );

  return (
    <BottomSheetModalProvider>
      <BottomSheetModal
        ref={ref}
        index={0}
        snapPoints={snapPoints}
        {...props}>
        {/* THE MAIN CONTAINER */}
        <View onLayout={onContentLayout}>
          {/* YOUR CONTENT HERE */}
        </View>
      </BottomSheetModal>
    </BottomSheetModalProvider>
  );
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the best workaround I've got so far. I've dropped the use of `useBottomSheetDynamicSnapPoints` as you proposed.
Additionally, I've removed `onLayout={onContentLayout}` completely and directly set my `snapPoints` based on the `Dimentions` util
`const snapPoints = React.useMemo(() => [Dimensions.get("screen").height - 40], []);` Also changed the `View` with `BottomSheetScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping the BottomSheetScrollView with a BottomSheetView and doing the onLayout there instead

Comment: Unfortunately, the behaviour stays the same.